# Calculate one variable based on changing input

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

I have the following function:

```js
function updateInput(ish){
    document.getElementById("BetAmount").value = ish;
}
```

I have the following HTML inputs:

```php
<input class="defaultText" type="number" name="BetAmount" id="BetAmount" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">

<input type="number" name="PotentialGain" id="PotentialGain" />
```

When users enter in a bet amount number(`BetAmount`), I would like to instantly show a calculated `PotentialGain`, which, for example, can be found by multiplying a constant by the specified bet amount entered in by the user.

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What?? There is no PHP5 input event that I know of... PHP is all on the server side...

Comment: there is no PHP here, just HTML and JavaScript

Comment: What you have is in the first example javascript and in the second example HTML. There is no PHP in either example you've shown.

Comment: Sorry I meant the HTML5 input event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct - you are showing the result in the `BetAmount` field so no change is visible.

Change your code to:

```
document.getElementById("PotentialGain").value = ish;
```

Here's a [working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/nF72t/) I changed the event to `onkeyup` as `onchange` only happens on blur - i.e. when a field loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final JQuery function that I used.

```js
function changeBet(bet) {
var moneyline = <?php echo json_encode($win) ?>;
var gain = moneyline * bet;
document.getElementById("PotentialGain").value = gain;
}
```

Along with these inputs:

```php
<input type="text" name="BetAmount[]" id="BetAmount" onkeyup="changeBet(this.value);" >
<input type="number" name="PotentialGain" id="PotentialGain" />
```