# I am still new with JS and can't see my mistake for this basic calculation script

Tags: javascript, select

I got the code from 
[Calculate one variable based on changing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276221/calculate-one-variable-based-on-changing-input)

I have written the following based on my limited understanding

```
<td>
  <select name='breadstick'>
   <option value='0' selected >-- Choose Breadstick --</option>
   <option value='4.06'>Breadstick</option>
   <option value='3.8'>Melba Toast</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input id="input_bread" type="text" name="input_bread" style="width:50px;" onkeyup="do_calc3(this.value);">
</td>
<td>
<input id="bread_results" class="" readonly name="bread_results" style="width:50px;" value="" />

<script>
function do_calc3() {
var bread_choice = document.getElementById('breadstick');
var bread_weight = document.getElementById('input_bread');
var bread_r = bread_choice * bread_weight;
document.getElementById("bread_results").value = bread_r;
}
</script>
</td>
```

Comment: First issue is that there is no element with `id="breadstick"`, it is a `name` instead. Either add `id="breadstick"` to the `<select>` or use a different function to get a handle to the `<select>` you need, like [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) in modern browsers. Can use as `document.querySelectorAll('select[name="breadstick"]')`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's easier for people to answer your question if you can discuss what specifically has gone wrong, and what you've already tried to do in order to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

You need to use the `.value` property for **getting** the elements' values.

Change:

```
var bread_r = bread_choice * bread_weight;
```

to:

```
var bread_r = bread_choice.value * bread_weight.value;
```

In your original code, `bread_choice` and `bread_weight` are references to DOM elements. When you try to multiply them, that won't be a numerical result.

You are attempting to get their values (what's selected in the dropdown and what's typed in the textbox), so you should **get** them with `.value`.

It's similar to your next line, where you **set** the `bread_results` element's value with `.value = bread_r`.

**Second:**

Your `<select>` element doesn't have an `id` of "breadstick", it has a `name`. So change your element to be:

```
<select id='breadstick' name='breadstick'>
```

**or** change your retrieval of the element to be:

```
var bread_choice = document.querySelector('select[name="breadstick"]');
```

**Third:**

Since you are using the inline event handler for `onkeyup`, you are already passing `this.value`, which means the textbox's value. Therefore, you don't need to get the textbox and its value in the function. Just add a parameter and use it.

```
function do_calc3(bread_weight) {
    var bread_choice = document.getElementById('breadstick').value;
    var bread_r = bread_choice * bread_weight;
    document.getElementById("bread_results").value = bread_r;
}
```

**Fourth:**

You shouldn't use inline event handlers. For many reasons, it's better to handle events in your Javascript code. Here's an example of how I'd set it up. (note that the `onkeyup="do_calc3(this.value);"` was removed and done in the Javascript's `window.onload` event)

```
function do_calc3() {
    var bread_choice = document.getElementById('breadstick');
    var bread_weight = this;
    var bread_r = bread_choice.value * bread_weight.value;
    if (isNaN(bread_r)) {
        bread_r = "Invalid";
    }
    document.getElementById("bread_results").value = bread_r;
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + eventName] = callback;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("input_bread");
    addEvent(textbox, "keyup", do_calc3);
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Gtven/4/

Answer (score 0):

`<select name='breadstick' id='breadstick'>`

Above needs to be changed, as you don't have an id "breadstick" yet.
Below is a changed function in order to get the actual values of the elements and not just the elements.

```
function do_calc3() {
    var bread_choice = document.getElementById('breadstick').value;
    var bread_weight = document.getElementById('input_bread').value;
    var bread_r = bread_choice * bread_weight;
    document.getElementById("bread_results").value = bread_r;
}
```

And here I got you a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TwqC6/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value`:

```
var bread_choice = document.getElementById('breadstick').value;
var bread_weight = document.getElementById('input_bread').value;
```